# Outputs of an LSTM Cell

Tags: lstm, rnn

from each cell of lstm, what are the output's and what does they signify? i understand that there will be three outputs. A long term memory, short term memory and a output. But, i am little confused from colah blog which can be found [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). Here he shows that there will be three outputs, one is long term state and other two outputs are exactly same. What is the use of two outputs being same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs are the "cell state" which is transferred only to the next LSTM cell and the "hidden state" which goes to the next cell and also as an output of the layer (in the case LSTM should return sequences).